# How to save a figure in R within the code

Tags: r, density-plot

I am plotting 2 probability density functions of observed and modeled fields.
I have this code below:

```
# Import libraries
library("stringr")
library(ggplot2)

#EXTENDED Observations with reanalysis obervatory 085320
# load in the text files and convert to dataframe
directory = '/Users/jacob/Desktop/Master Meteorologia/PE/Datos/Lisboa/wind/00_Observed/Extended/Observed-Wind-Lisboa_Extended/'
filename = '085320_Wind_Extended.txt'

directory2 = '/Users/jacob/Desktop/Master Meteorologia/PE/Datos/Lisboa/wind/MPI-ESM-MR/Historical/'
filename2 = 'Wind_MPI-ESM-MR_Historical_085320.txt'

extFile = read.delim(str_c(directory,filename), header = FALSE, col.names=c("Year", "Month", "Day", "WindMagn"))
histFile = read.delim(str_c(directory2,filename2), header = FALSE, col.names=c("Year", "Month", "Day", "WindMagn"))

# Extract vecto==wind from both cases
windMagnExt = extFile$WindMagn
windMagnHist = histFile$WindMagn


### PDF observed and modelled
d= density(windMagnExt)
e= density(windMagnHist)
#png('/Users/jacob/Desktop/Master Meteorologia/PE/Figures/windMagnObsHist_PDF.png', width = 1000, height=1000, units='px' ,res=700, pointsize = 12)
plot(d, main="PDF of observed and modelled wind for Obs. 085320", col="red")
lines(e, col="blue" )
legend("topright", legend=c("Observed", "Modelled"),
       col=c("red", "blue"), lty=1:2, cex=0.8)
grid()
#dev.off()
```

It gives me this type of plot:

[image]

However, there are 2 things I still want to be done.

1. In the legend, the modelled field is a dashed line when it is not. How do I change this.
2. I try to uncomment 2 lines png() and dev.off() to save the figure within the code and not have to use the export button in RStudio. I do it as follows:

```
### PDF observed and modelled
d= density(windMagnExt)
e= density(windMagnHist)
png('/Users/jacob/Desktop/Master Meteorologia/PE/Figures/windMagnObsHist_PDF.png', width = 15, height=10, units='px' ,res=700, pointsize = 12)
plot(d, main="PDF of observed and modelled wind for Obs. 085320", col="red")
lines(e, col="blue" )
legend("topright", legend=c("Observed", "Modelled"),
       col=c("red", "blue"), lty=1:2, cex=0.8)
grid()
dev.off()
```

But then it gives me this error. I tried saving other figures using this before, but now it tells me that *figure margins are too large*

[image]

EDIT:

Based on D.J's comment below i tried running png() without any parameters:

```
### PDF observed and modelled
d= density(windMagnExt)
e= density(windMagnHist)
png('/Users/jacob/Desktop/Master Meteorologia/PE/Figures/windMagnObsHist_PDF.png', res=300)
plot(d, main="PDF of observed and modeled wind for Obs. 085320", col="red", xlab='Wind speed (m/s)')
lines(e, col="blue" )
legend("topright", legend=c("Observed", "Modeled"),
       col=c("red", "blue"), lty=1:1, cex=0.8)
grid()
dev.off()
```

It gives me the plot I want but, when adding the parameter ***res=300***, I still get the same error as above.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: It seems you are trying to make a png that 15px wide and 10px tall. That's very small. Try increasing the width and height to something more reasonable for an image. The default is 480x480

Comment: a) you are using lty = 1:2 in your legend which results in one full and one dashed line.
b) try to run your png without specifying any parameters other than filepath and name. if it works you can start playing with parameters

Comment: I tried changing it to 480x480 and something larger but it still gives me the same error.